# Unix - Percentage calc, result should be abs

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

In unix bash script I am trying to calculate percentage variance between two numbers:

$ Value1=3947 
$ Value2=5853 
$ echo "$Value1" "$Value2" | awk '{print ($1-$2)/$1*100}' 
-48.2898

The above command works perfectly fine for me but I want the result to be abs (+ve number), could someone help me to achieve this.

Thanks,

Comment: I just realised the way I am calculating variance difference also not correct. So could someone help me how to find the variance percentage between two numbers and I want the output as abs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, awk does come with an abs() function built-in. Implement it:

```awk
function abs(x) {
    return (x<0 ? -x : x)
}
```

testing

```
$ awk -v a=42 -v b=-3.14 '
      function abs(x) {
          return (x<0 ? -x : x)
      }
      BEGIN {
          print abs(a)
          print abs(b)
      }'
42
3.14
```